# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't create bitmap without a color space

Tags: android

I got the above error when rendering my custom view, The error happend at this line `val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,0,bmp.height-height,width,height)` , the  width and height of `bmt` Bitmap is bigger than the one i want to clip.  Who has idea for this problem? Thanks for first!!!

```
 rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
           override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
               rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
               rootView.buildDrawingCache()
                val bmp: Bitmap = rootView.getDrawingCache()
               Timber.d(" test ${bmp.width} ${bmp.height}  $x $y   $width $height")
               val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,0,bmp.height-height,width,height)
               background = BitmapDrawable(context.resources, b)
                return true
            }
        })
```